# Trouble GamePad input on iOS but works perfect on Android

Tags: unity, c#

I am having trouble getting input from on iOS devices (iPhone 6 Plus and iPad). Here is my code,

```
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.JoystickButton14))// A
    {
        chr_show = "A";
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.JoystickButton13))// B
    {
        chr_show = "B";
    }
         ...........................................

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.JoystickButton11))// Select
    {
        chr_show = "SELECT";
    }
```

And in OnGUI()

```
    GUI.Label (new Rect(0,0,100,100), "Pressed Button : "+chr_show, guiStyle);
```

Code works perfect on Android device. I also have tried following:
[image: Input Manager Inspector]

```
        if (Input.GetButton ("JSButton"))// JSButton
        {
            chr_show = "JS Button 14";
        }
```

Please Help Me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you validated that the gamepad gets connected on device? The following page in the manual uses a script to check that the controller connection was a success. Use GUI to display the connection.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-joystick.html

Next step is to validate the button configuration.

Comment: Yes, I tried this too but 'Input.GetJoystickNames();' always returns 0. But joystick work for iOS OS.